# request_uri and array those kind of stuff

Tags: php, uri

I have a code which I need help on.

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/testmore/' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/testmore/home') { $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/testmore/index'; }

    echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo '<br>';


    $page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    function dostuff($pagesC) { echo 'yes!<br>'; echo $pagesC.'<br>'; }


    $pageArray = Array('index', 'login'); 

$directory = '/testmore/'; // Directory if in one. Otherwise, leave it as '/'.  

    $uriArray = explode('/', strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $directory));
      if (in_array($uriArray[0], $pageArray)) {
        dostuff($uriArray[0]); } else {
        echo '404'; }
```

This uses URI requests and it makes it from `http://link.com/index.php?page=$VARIABLE` to `http://link.com/variable`

I have all the `.htaccess` done and working which wont be a problem.
The problem is that when I type `http://link.com/testmore/index` it wont show that specified page, but instead a 404 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have to do any work in the PHP page. The reason your pages aren't working is because your .htaccess code is incorrect. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The above will mask redirect `http://link.com/testmore/index` to `http://link.com/index.php?page=testmore&sub=index`. It will also redirect `http://link.com/variable` to `http://link.com/index.php?page=variable`.

```
$uriArray = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (in_array($uriArray[1], $pageArray)){
     dostuff($uriArray[1]);
else
     echo '404';
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying but What I want is `http://link.com/testmore/index` atm nothing more nothing less. the code in the OP is my index.php for /testmore/

Comment: Edit your .htaccess file to use the code above, and you won't need all that wizard code in your PHP files...

Comment: ok, if you didn't look at the code, I dont have any `GET` requests. I just wanted to use `REQUEST_URI` to make `http://link.com/testmore/variable` instead of using `GET`. Also I've tried to use `GET`, but it never worked. What I am now asking is just get the 404 into showing the right page. otherwise everything works fine.

Comment: I did add it. But I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: I got it it was `$uriArray = explode($directory, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`